# What is best solution to implement a list of tags in SQL?

Tags: sql, list, left-join

I want to add a new column that contains a list of tags to an existing table named `QUESTION`.

Example:

| QuestionID | Tag's List |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | SQL,UNION |
| 823 | C++,TEMPLATE,CLASS |

I see 2 choices

1. I create a new column with sufficient spaces to contain the list

```
    ALTER TABLE question
    ADD tags_list VARCHAR(400);
```

2. I create a new table for containing these tags (one tag per record)

```
    CREATE TABLE question_key
        ( questionID INT 
        , tag        VARCHAR(40)
        )
```

| questionID | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | SQL |
| 201 | UNION |
| 823 | C++ |
| 823 | TEMPLATE |
| 823 | CLASS |

The `tags` to add are similar to `tags` used on StackOverflow.

For each row in table, it is possible to have at maximum 10 tags smaller that 40 characters.

Just for information, SELECT criteria related to these keys will be

```
SELECT * WHERE key-list CONTAINS 'key1'
SELECT * WHERE key-list CONTAINS 'key1' OR 'key2'
SELECT * WHERE key-list CONTAINS 'key1' AND 'key2'
SELECT * WHERE key-list CONTAINS 'key1' BUT NOT 'key2'
SELECT * WHERE key-list CONTAINS 'key1' BUT (NOT 'key2' AND NOT 'key3')
SELECT * WHERE key-list CONTAINS-ONLY ('key1','key2','key3')
```

I know that I can use `REGEX` for solution 1 and `JOIN`, `VIEW`, `GROUP BY` or `PARTITION BY` for solution 2.

What is the best solution to implement ? Why ?

At `SQL` level, I think that solution 2 is the best, but for simplicity I prefer solution 1.

Comment: Can you tag DBMS(preferably with its version) please

Comment: Hey, what kind of DB engine are you using? That may help a lot with the answers you may receive. For example, doing this in a relational DB will give you a lot of subjections to normalize the data. Or maybe a NOSQL DB you can query with strings instead.

Comment: For an RDBMS the answer seems quite simple: As you want to query separate tags, store them separately. Storing them as a list in a string would violate the first normalization form 1NF and thus hinder queries and changes to the tags list. If you didn't want to look at separate tags within your DBMS (just as you are not insterested in single pixels inside the DBMS when storing a picture) you could store the tags as a string instead.

Comment: If this is like stackoverflow tags where the tags must be chosen from a list, then I would urge you to even have a tags table along with the mentioned question_tag table with proper foreign keys installed.

Comment: I search a solution for PostGresql but also for Oracle or SqlServer or MariaDb. My question is for any DB in fact. @Thorsten: I have already a table with all possible tags.

Comment: @philipxy: YES - I see now that my question has a duplicate question/answer !

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Solution 2 for a couple of reasons

1. Imagine your table growing and queries which cannot use index growing slower and slower. Solution 2 will allow for efficient queries.  You could actually write filtering queries directly on question_key mapping table without bringing in data from question table columns upfront. Likely the queries in solution 1 are non sargable.
2. Imagine when you need to remove a tag altogether (like burnination in SO) or update the name say from sql-server to MS-Sql-Server. It is more easily done on solution 2.

Comment: but in term of SELECT performance this will slow down simple SELECT without WHERE clause using conditions on tags ! Thats is 98% of SELECT commands.